# Ubuntu Desktop Environment Change To KDE

Tags: kde

What is the best way to "upgrade" my Ubuntu 10.10 desktop to KDE 4.8?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/kde)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubuntu 12.04 Precise ships with KDE 4.8, but since 12.04 is still in development, I suggest you to wait a month before the final release.

You can get a daily image from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/daily-live/current/ for testing purposes. If you care about stability, I'd suggest you not to "upgrade" unless you want to spend time on debugging.

Comment: Thanks Lekensteyn. I read about KDE 4.8 in Linnux Format mag. and it looked good. But as I'm fairly new the idea of debugging does not appeal. Will try Kubuntu when it's settled down.

Comment: If you're new, I suggest you to wait for 1-2 months and try 12.04. I'm currently using Kubuntu 11.10 amd64 btw.